# How to force a Text component to adapt to the content in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I've a `Text` nested in a `View`, I would like that the Text autoresize itself getting only the effective required space, but this seems to be impossible...

This is the link to the snack I've done:
https://snack.expo.dev/@david92/flexshrink-text

I would expect the green block to end immediately after the words "very" and "word"...
How can I change the current behavior?

[image]

This is a screenshot of the current result...

Answer (score 0):

Change your code in your container style to this.

```
  container: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
```

Comment: I tried adding `alignSelf: 'flex-start'` but the situation is the same... obviously I have not removed the property `width` as otherwise it would change the very nature of the problem

Comment: The problem is with the width. You are forcing the text to be within the width size. That's why the text is pushed to the bottom.

Comment: the problem is not the text on 2 lines, the problem is that I would expect the green block to end immediately after the words "very" and "word"